# Rename another buffer

Tags: buffers

There are buffers that prevent you from being able to execute interactive commands (by overriding the default <kbd>M-x</kbd> binding). For example, `*ansi-term*` buffer would do this.

(I know you can do <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> to invoke the command).

Is there an existing way to rename a buffer that isn't the current buffer? (It's easy to write a function for it, but it seems like it should've been already written...)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no predefined command to rename a buffer other than the current one (e.g. read a buffer name). It's easy to define such a command, though.

Comment: @Drew Well, I guess, I'll have to accept that I have to write such a function.

Comment: You might want to wait a bit, to see if someone else provides info about this. I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a function that can rename a buffer that isn't the current buffer, here's one way to do it.

```lisp
(defun rename-another-buffer (buffer new-name)
  "Rename a buffer that isn't the current buffer."
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (rename-buffer new-name)))
```

It uses [`with-current-buffer`](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Current-Buffer#macro-with-current-buffer-buffer-or-name-body) to temporarily make the given buffer the current buffer so that [`rename-buffer`](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Buffer-Names#command-rename-buffer-newname-optional-unique) can be used on it.

Comment: I would venture that the OP was looking for an interactive command, where you select a buffer to be renamed first interactively.